# Why does this MySQL Query returns two rows?

Tags: mysql, database

my query returns two rows where second is the exact duplicate of first. i would like to know the reason why is it happening? i know if i put the LIMIT 1 in the end it will return only a single row so i would request not to suggest this solution. here is my query

```
SELECT u.username,u.password,u.registerDate,u.lastVisitDate,u.lastVisitIp,
u.activationString,
u.active,u.block,u.contact_id,c.name,c.email,c.pPhone,c.sPhone,c.rPhone,c.area_id,
a.name as areaName, a.city_id, ct.name as cityName, ct.state_id, s.name as stateName, 
s.country_id, cn.name as countryName 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN contacts c 
ON (u.contact_id = c.id) 
LEFT JOIN areas a 
ON (c.area_id = a.id) 
LEFT JOIN cities ct 
ON (a.city_id = ct.id) 
LEFT JOIN states s 
ON (ct.state_id = s.id) 
LEFT JOIN countries cn 
ON (s.country_id = c.id) 
WHERE u.id = 1
```

Above query is fetching data from 6 tables which includes

```
users s
contacts c
areas a
cities ct
states s
country cn
```

all 6 tables above have primary key named `id` the foreign keys are as follows

```
users.conntact_id
contacts.area_id
areas.city_id
cities.state_id
states.country_id
```

why is it returning two rows instead of one?

Comment: are you sure for all the conditions in query you have 1 one and not 2 rows?

Comment: yes i am sure, the users table have only 1 record with id 1

Comment: but may be in other table there are 2 rows for user id=1 ???

Comment: @ Harry there is no foreign key for user id in any of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the tables you join into has more than one element, thus all the others are repeated. This table most probably is the `contacts` table.

Comment: i am sorry but i am unable to understand what exactly are you trying to explain?

Comment: @Ibrahim - if you have 2 matching records in the `contacts` table, how many rows should be returned?

Comment: @Oded it was only yesterday when i learnt JOIN :) , is LEFT JOIN not supposed to return the result Only if it finds match FROM Table A.

Comment: @Ibrahim - Yes. And if there are several matches in Table B, they will all be returned with the rows from A being duplicated.

Comment: @Oded of course two, you see i don't have two matching tables in contacts, i have only two records in contacts table with id 1 and 3

Comment: @Ibrahim - than it will be one of the other tables. Go through all the joins.

Comment: aaah i got it, i have records in areas where it has more then one matches. and now i understand the reason.. thank you Oded for your explaination that helped me :)